# webpack resolves CSS/SASS imports in wrong order

Tags: css, sass, webpack, webpack-style-loader

When using css and sass imports in the same file, the order of the generated css is not correct.

the full example can be seen and reproduced here: https://github.com/p0wl/webpack-jimdo-example/tree/master/sass-order

Given we have the following setup:

```
@import 'some.sass';

.legacy_bundle {
    content: 'legacy_bundle';
}

@import 'middle.css';
@import 'other.sass';
```

output:

```
.middle {
    content: 'middle';
}.some {
  content: 'some'; }

.legacy_bundle {
  content: 'legacy_bundle'; }

.other {
  content: 'other'; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=new_cms_classes.css.map*/
```

`.middle` is the first rule, although it is not the first import. `.some` needs to be the first rule, as it is the first import.

webpack.config.js (extract):

```
    entry: {
        "new_cms_classes.css": "legacy_bundle.css"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            [
                {
                    test: /\.sass$/,
                    // Passing indentedSyntax query param to node-sass
                    loader: "sass?indentedSyntax"
                },
                {
                    test: /legacy_.+\.css$/,
                    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader?root=~!sass")
                },
                { 
                    test: /\.css$/, loaders: ["style", "css?root=~"] 
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
```

webpack and all loaders are at the latest release.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698230/keep-import-at-the-end-of-css-after-scss-compile

Answer (score 0):

This issue is opened [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/215)

Possibly it may be the cause of using CommonChunkPlugin.

In my case, the reason was in using ExtractTextPluginto compress classNames in stylesheets, like this

```js
  if (isProd) {
     config.module.loaders[1].loader = ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 
                                                                 'css?modules&sourceMap&localIdentName[local]_[hash:base64:10]!sass!css');
  }
```

Actually, in my case, stylesheets was not mixed, but had other classes, so reset.scss file had main priority. Check out your webpack.config.js file, the place, where you compress styles in prod mode.

Comment: @Michal I'm not sure. After all, saying that an unexpected behaviour isn't due to a user error but to a bug that has been officially recognized is, somehow, an answer. It implies that the solution (or *one* solution) is to wait for a patch.